# Search detected faces from a database OpenCV

Tags: c++, database, opencv, codeblocks, face-detection

I am working with this Code:

[Program sample](http://derindelimavi.blogspot.de/2008/05/yz-tanma-2.html)

the above link has been programmed with the help of this page: 
[Servo Magazine](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/index.html)

This Code can do Extract face, learn face and save the learn face in a database with a label(example: chris_laughing.bmp or chris_sad.bmp). It can be recognize the face that the User saved in a Database.

My Project is send a E-Mail to user if the Person not in the database.

- i included a function to send a E-Mail to the user.

So i have saved 2 different Images from 2 Stars chris and john. When i click recognize they show me the correctly star with label(example: chris_laughing.bmp) from the database.

The Problem is if i Extract(detect) a face from a other star or person (also not chris not john) the Code show me the NEAREST star from the database.

What i want is that the Program give me a Messagebox that say: this Person is not in the database.

Is it possible with this Program(code)??

Comment: You, probably, understand that after crossing some threshold (or set of thresholds) the person can become identified "not in database" instead of being identified as "nearest". The problem is to set the threshold correctly depending on the precision of algorithm and data available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That program works by assuming that face images for each person lie in a subspace different to that for other people. This idea can work really well in some situations. The program learns a subspace for each person and when you input a new image it measures the distance to all subspaces it has previously learned and chooses the nearest one.

The program doesn't seem to have any sort of check that the image is too far from all learned subspaces. However, it would be an interesting exercise to try to add that feature.

Here is a some info about the main idea in the software: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface

Comment: Thank u. Have u got any ideas how can i release that with using OpenCV?

Comment: Best idea would be to read some of the references on the wiki page I referred to? You do realize that the program already heavily uses OpenCV? It would be a big job to rewrite it without OpenCV, and I am not sure why one would want to. In findNearestNeighbor(), if distSq is too big (need testing or machine learning to work out what "too big" is) return -1 instead of iNearest. Tthen of course you need to change what happens where findNearestNeighbor() is called if -1 is returned.

Comment: thank you I have also thought so. That the program rather than the inearest low-pass outputs an error.

Or i do it so give a Message if any face detected :)